# Odd returning of ArrayList#size()

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I am trying to get a random `ArrayList` in a `HashMap`, and when I look at all the ArrayLists in the `HashMap` the size of everything is 2 as it should.

The problem occurs when I try to add an `ArrayList` from the `Hashmap` into another. It then returns the size as 0 even though the size of all lists in the `HashMap` are 2. Does anyone see why?

```
for(Point p : defensePossibilities.keySet())
    System.out.println(defensePossibilities.get(p).size());

ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
while(points == null) {
    try {
        int random = rnd.nextInt(defensePossibilities.size());
        points.addAll(
                defensePossibilities.get(random));
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
System.out.println("PointsSize: " + points.size());

int piece2 = rnd.nextInt(points.size());
```

This is what it returns in the stacktrace

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
PointsSize: 0
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.board.White_AI.move(White_AI.java:95)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.board.ChessBoard.tick(ChessBoard.java:29)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.board.ChessBoard.<init>(ChessBoard.java:21)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.Game.render(Game.java:124)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.Game.run(Game.java:70)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 95 is

```
int piece2 = rnd.nextInt(
```

Why is the size of `points` 0 if all the ArrayLists in the `HashMap` are at the size of 2?

Comment: `while(points == null)` <- That's never going to be true. You never add anything to `points`.

Comment: That's it. resueman is right. An empty ArrayList is never null but has only a length of 0.  Use the isEmpty() method instead of == null.

Comment: If its not true then how does it pass through it?

Comment: @TheGamerPlayz It only passes through once it's not true. Once the statement is evaluated as false, then it stops repeating the loop.

Comment: Can you tell us how defensePossibilities is defined? Is it a HashMap<Point, ArrayList<Point>>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

points not is null because you have instantiated it.
`ArrayList<Point> points;` this is null
So replace your code

```
for(Point p : defensePossibilities.keySet())
    System.out.println(defensePossibilities.get(p).size());

ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
while(points.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        int random = rnd.nextInt(defensePossibilities.size());
        points.addAll(
                defensePossibilities.get(random));
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
System.out.println("PointsSize: " + points.size());

int piece2 = rnd.nextInt(points.size());
```

**UPDATE** 
change

```
points.addAll(defensePossibilities.keySet());
```

**2 UPDATE**

> public V get(Object key) Returns the value to which the specified key
>   is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

So

```
ArrayList<Point> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.addAll(defensePossibilities.keySet());
int random = rnd.nextInt(defensePossibilities.size());
points.add(a.get(random))
```

Comment: I changed it to #isEmpty and it has been in that loop for 8.5 million loops now...

Comment: Replace points.addAll(
                defensePossibilities.get(random)) with points.addAll(
                defensePossibilities);

Comment: I am trying to get a random ArrayList from inside of the HashMap defense possibilities, so I that would cause a new error in itself

Comment: Ok I now see your second post, but I am not trying to add all the keys or all the values. I am trying to add a single randomly selected ArrayList that is a value in defensePossibilities.

Comment: TheGamerPlayz defensePossibilities.get(key) return a value with this key. Are you sure that random is a valid key?

Comment: You know what I didn't even think about that. I was mixing up HashMaps and ArrayLists. Thanks

Comment: int random = rnd.nextInt(defensePossibilities.size());
points.add(a.get(random));  is dangerous, because you can run into an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if random == a.size()! Consider my answer some lines below.

Answer (score 4):

replace `points == null` with `points.isEmpty()`

`points` variable is not null because you assign `points` variable an arraylist before the while loop. I assume what you want to do is to check while the poinst list is empty. So making the suggested change will solve your problem.

```
for(Point p : defensePossibilities.keySet())
    System.out.println(defensePossibilities.get(p).size());

ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
while(points == null) { // points is not null, it is just empty
// replace points == null with points.isEmpty()
    try {
        int random = rnd.nextInt(defensePossibilities.size());
        points.addAll(
                defensePossibilities.get(random));
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
System.out.println("PointsSize: " + points.size());

int piece2 = rnd.nextInt(points.size());
```

Comment: When I use #isEmpty it gets stuck in an eternal loop.

Comment: Well if there is a problem do you know what it is?

Comment: I dont know , i must see your whole code to find the problem

Comment: The code here is everything that needs to be given. Nothing else changes this outside of adding to defensePossibilities

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem, after using isEmpty() instead of == null, is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

In your code the value of random can be as large as the size of your List. Let's say you have 10 Objects inside and random is 10:

defensePossibilities.get(random); // 10 object = indexes 0 to 9, but not 10!

Remember that Lists, as Arrays do, start indexing by 0.

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());    
}
```

And you'll se what i mean. ;o)